# PHP converting variable string to int

Tags: php

To start, I could not find this answer online because of the way my variable string is defined.  Normally I should be able to add 0 to the variable, or use (int), but it does not work.

```
<?php

$casestringid = "'118'";
$caseid = $casestringid + 0;

echo $casestringid;

echo $caseid;

?>
```

Output: '118'0

As you can see, because of the way my first variable is declared, the standard methods of converting a string to an integer does not work.  My `$casestringid` is written like that because it requests a number from another page.  Rather than trying to change how to format that, I figure it will be  easier for help on how to convert a string that looks like that, into an integer.  I would like the output of `caseid` to be 118.  Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Replace (remove) the single quotes first then type cast as integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have no other chance like this:

```
intval(str_replace("'",'',$casestringid));
```

Comment: someone said the exact same thing a minute before you.  Thanks though it is right!

Comment: wait nvm you said it before

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `'118'` is *not* an integer as far as the [PHP](http://php.net/) parser is concerned, it's a string. It looks like an integer to us, of course, but it has slashes (`'`) which make it "unconvertible".

Use [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for this:

```
intval(str_replace("'", '', $casestringid));
```

Comment: typecasting (int) str_replace(...) is performanter then intval()

Comment: @donald123 That's true. In this case we are using `intval` with base 10, so it's better to use int casting. `0 + str_replace(...)` would be even faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try `intval ($casestringid) + 0`.

**EDIT:**

How about this, then:

```
filter_var ($casestringid, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Comment: I dont think intval will digest quotes.

Comment: i think intval would result in zero.

Comment: You are mistaken, one of the many curiosities of PHP is the way it handles string-to-int conversion. It will basically take the largest substring of digits starting at index 0 it can find, and discard the rest, then convert those to int. For instance, saying `intval('51 pigs')` will return `51`. EDIT: Never mind, I just noticed the `'` at index 0.

Comment: I'm still getting the same result.  `$caseid` is still 0

Comment: @Thanix using your example, it would be `intval("'51 pigs'")` which will return 0

Answer (score 1):

Replace the '':

```
intval(str_replace("'",'',$casestringid));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the single quotes and use [`intval().`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)

```
<?php

$casestringid = "'118'";
$parseid = str_replace("'", "", $casestringid);
$caseid = intval($parseid);

echo $casestringid;

echo $caseid;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$casestringid = "'118'";
$int = str_replace("'", "", $casestringid);
echo intval($int);
```

Comment: should still use `intval()` even after the string is replaced

Answer (score 0):

If it is just an integer you are looking for, this could work.
it will remove any non digit characters then return it as an int

```
function parseInt( $s ){
    return (int)(preg_replace( '~\D+~' , '' , $s ));
}
```